# How to do merge sort without using additional arrays for splitting the initial array?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, mergesort

I was trying to solve a problem which asks to write merge sort code but without using additional arrays for partitioning the initial array. I guess the code is wrote is almost good but the problem I am facing is that I can't figure out how to maintain and update the array while being sorted. I know the problem is in Merge function.

How can I fix the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void PrintArray(int A[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void merge(int A[], int left, int mid, int right, int n){
  
int B[n];

int i = left, j = mid+1, k=0;

while(i<=mid && j <= right){

  if(A[i]>=A[j]){
    B[k++] = A[i++];
  }

  else {
    B[k++] = A[j++];
  }

}

while(i<=mid){
  B[k++] = A[i++];
}

while(j<=right){
  B[k++] = A[j++];
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  A[i] = B[i];
}

}

void MergeSort(int A[], int left, int right, int n)
{ 
  if(left<right){
    int mid;
    mid = floor((left+right)/2);
    MergeSort(A,left,mid,n/2);
    MergeSort(A,mid+1,right,n/2);
    merge(A,left,mid,right,n);
  }

  else return;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int A[n];

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        
    MergeSort(A, 0, n-1, n);
    PrintArray(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort is giving a bunch of algorithms using two arrays (source and destination) only. Or you are looking for an in-place algorithm?

Comment: How do you expect to "partition" anything in a single array? You can if you double the array size and use offsets, but that is no different than doing it correctly using separate arrays for partitioning.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I guess we do not need to partition the array in real. We can virtually partition it using the variable left, right, and mid because we can virtually create two arrays out of one by limiting the first one from left to mid and then the other one from mid+1 to right.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I thought that using a single extra array as a temporary storage for sorting and then copying it back to the initial array would be considered as an in-place algorithm, but as Craig mentioned that this approach could sometimes cause stack overflow and is not truly a in-place approach so I guess my method is not accurate. But I tried it like this because the problem specifically said we can't create 2 extra arrays for partitioning and gave a code structure to fill that's why we can't even create any more functions like in the Wikipedia solution

Comment: @SuryanshManav you have more than one array. You have the VLA `A` declared in `main()` and `B` declared in `merge()`. And since you call `merge()` recursively from `MergeSort()`, you create 3 more VLAs per-level of recursion. You likely have dozens of arrays in use by the time it is all said and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the final `for` loop in `merge`, change:

```
A[i] = B[i];
```

Into:

```
A[left + i] = B[i];
```

---

**Edit:** Even after that fix, the sort was still wrong. The correct fix for the final loop is:

```
for (i = left;  i <= right;  ++i)
    A[i] = B[i - left];
```

The original `for (i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)` didn't work because just passing `n / 2` could pass a value that was one less than needed. With this new fix, `n` doesn't need to be passed to `merge` at all. So, `n` is really only needed for the public function. See the UPDATE section below.

---

*Side notes:*

You don't need to use `floor` at all. It's superfluous for integer math [and might make the results *less* accurate].

You are sorting in *reverse* order (e.g. `3, 2, 1` instead of `1, 2, 3`). To sort in *ascending* order, in `merge`, change: `if (A[i] >= A[j])` to `if (A[i] <= A[j])`

You are not creating an *initial* extra array, but you have `B` on the stack in `merge`, so, you *are* using an auxiliary/temp array. This is true regardless whether you copy from `A` to `B` at the start of `merge` or copy back from `B` to `A` at the end of `merge`

So, you don't have a true "in-place" algorithm.

In fact, for large enough arrays, having `B` on the stack would cause a stack overflow. It might be better to use a heap allocation for `B`.

You could put this in a global/public "wrapper" function for `mergeSort` (e.g. `mergeSortPublic`). Do (e.g.) `B = malloc(sizeof(int) * n)` at the start and do `free(B)` at the end. You can make `B` global scope or pass it as an extra arg to your merge functions

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a fully cleaned up version that adds diagnostic tests.

Because of the change in the final loop in `merge`, it no longer needs the `n` value. So, it's no longer needed in `mergeSort` either with the `mergeSortPub` change.

I refactored the first loop in `merge` to be slightly faster by not refetching already fetched array values. The optimizer *might* have found this speedup, but I think it's better to state it explicitly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void
PrintArray(int A[], int n)
{
    int totlen = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        totlen += printf(" %d", A[i]);
        if (totlen >= 72) {
            printf("\n");
            totlen = 0;
        }
    }

    if (totlen > 0)
        printf("\n");
}

void
merge(int A[], int left, int mid, int right, int *B)
{

    int i = left,
        j = mid + 1,
        k = 0;

    int Ai = A[i];
    int Aj = A[j];

    while (i <= mid && j <= right) {
        if (Ai <= Aj) {
            B[k++] = Ai;
            Ai = A[++i];
        }
        else {
            B[k++] = Aj;
            Aj = A[++j];
        }
    }

    while (i <= mid)
        B[k++] = A[i++];

    while (j <= right)
        B[k++] = A[j++];

    // original code
#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = B[i];
#endif

    // first fix -- still broken
#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[left + i] = B[i];
#endif

    // correct fix
#if 1
    for (i = left;  i <= right;  ++i)
        A[i] = B[i - left];
#endif
}

void
MergeSort(int A[], int left, int right, int *B)
{
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        MergeSort(A, left, mid, B);
        MergeSort(A, mid + 1, right, B);
        merge(A, left, mid, right, B);
    }
}

void
MergeSortPub(int A[], int n)
{
    int *B = malloc(sizeof(*B) * n);

    MergeSort(A,0,n - 1,B);

    free(B);
}

void
dotest(int tstno)
{

    int n = rand() % 1000;

    int *A = malloc(sizeof(*A) * n);

    for (int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)
        A[i] = n - i;

    MergeSortPub(A,n);

    int old = A[0];
    int bad = 0;
    for (int i = 1;  i < n;  ++i) {
        int cur = A[i];
        if (cur < old) {
            if (! bad)
                printf("dotest: %d -- i=%d old=%d cur=%d\n",tstno,i,old,cur);
            bad = 1;
        }
        old = cur;
    }

    if (bad) {
        PrintArray(A,n);
        exit(1);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    int n;

#if 0
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int A[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);

    MergeSortPub(A, n);
    PrintArray(A, n);
#else
    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= 1000;  ++tstno)
        dotest(tstno);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig for your comments and for correcting the code. I updated the for loop as per your recommendation and it passed all the test results now. But I guess we still need "n" in the functions in order to declare the B array otherwise how would we know the size? Also, the only two functions allowed were the Merge and the MergeSort functions as the problem gave the code template with those parameters already in there. And yeah I did the sort in descending order coz the question asked it in that manner.

Comment: Honestly, I don't truly understand what in-place algorithm means so I thought this approach as an in-place one, but as you mentioned that it can coz overflow errors for large inputs I get an idea now. Also, I get it now. Using floor for integer calculations is not useful at all, maybe what I wanted was ceil LOL but I am happy that it worked after updating the for loop as suggested by you. I was working on it from a long time and was quite clueless when I posted it here. Thanks again for your time and effort. ;))

Comment: This method is using an additional array the same size as the original array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few variations of merge sort that do not use any additional space other than local variables. Optimal implementations of this are complicated and about 50% slower than conventional merge sort, and most of these implementations are for academic research.

There is a wiki article for one variation, that is hybrid of insertion and merge sort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort

Link to a more optimized version in grailsort.h in this github repository. The void GrailSort(SORT_TYPE *arr,int Len) function does not use any additional buffer.

https://github.com/Mrrl/GrailSort